# Why 'head' (from the prelude package) has not been implemented the safe way with a Maybe?

Tags: haskell

In prelude, [head](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:head) has the following signature : `head :: [a] -> a` which makes it unsafe on empty list, which is not good !! (`head :: [a] -> Maybe a` is the good way :-) )

this applies for a couple of other functions on list : last, tail, init minimum, maximum, cycle, last, init, foldl1, cycle... there are actually a lot of these calling `errorEmptyList`

Quoting *Stephen Diehl* from his [website](http://www.stephendiehl.com/posts/protolude.html) :

> "Safe provides Maybe versions of many of the various partial functions
>   (head, tail) that are shipped by default. Wrapping it up in a Maybe is
>   widely considered the right approach and if Haskell were designed
>   today, they would not be present."

I would love to see these unsafe functions tagged somehow with some convention at least because I don't think any of us like when an exception blows up in production :-)

What prevents the community from fixing these issues in the prelude ?

Comment: Backwards compatibility seems like a good reason.. besides, wouldn't you just be moving the empty-check from the calling site to the receiving site?

Comment: I agree it would have been a good idea to make a signature `head :: Unsafe => [a] -> a`, such that one can "turn off" unsafe functions, but unfortunately it is "too late", by introducing that, it would break a lot of existing code. Furthermore a lot of functions have been designed *without* such signature, hence it would be of "limited" use.

Comment: One of the main problems is that you can use unsafe functions in such a way, that the result itself is safe. For example one can use `head`, but if you know for sure you are dealing with a non-empty list, then this is not unsafe, so you can make a very *conservative* approach where you mark everything that uses unsafe functions as unsafe. But this will act like a "virus" contaminating a lot of functions that are safe.

Comment: @thebjorn , usually it's a good practice to unlift a Maybe/Either at the highest layer because then you have a better context to treat the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The community has been fixing this issue in the *custom* preludes that are distributed on Hackage.
But it can't fix the prelude itself, it's up to the Haskell Committee in charge. For matters of backward compatibility, it has never been fixed.

(I personally prefer [Relude](https://github.com/kowainik/relude)'s approach on that matter. This prelude's `head` function is typed as `NonEmpty a -> a`.)

Comment: Wow you made me discover something today ! Do you know other attempts to rewrite the prelude ?

Comment: @NicolasHenin There are quite a few of custom preludes on hackage. One of the better one IMHO is the https://hackage.haskell.org/package/foundation
Another very practical one, that I use on daily basis is https://hackage.haskell.org/package/rio

Comment: Check out Aelve's list on alternative preludes: https://guide.aelve.com/haskell/alternative-preludes-zr69k1hc

Answer (score 4):

The real question is why there is a function `head` *at all*. This isn't needed for working with lists. To case-separate `(x:_)` and `[]`, as “safe head” would allow you, the best option is to just use pattern matching, or suitable higher-order functions / lens operators.

In practice, the only use for `head` is when you're in some big function, want at the head of some list `xs` (among many other parameters) where you *have already checked that it is nonempty*, e.g. because some other clause has already covered that. In that case, the safety would be redundant.

Arguably, this is still a kludge and would better be expressed with pattern-matching. But the point is, the unsafe head has at least some ugly-but-pragmatic uses, whereas a safe head would mostly add extra noise to pattern matching that needs to be done anyway.

IMO, `head`, `tail` and `!!` should just be deprecated, not changed. They keep tripping up beginners coming from Python etc. thinking that they need such functions, but actually this style is inherently against the grain of Haskell.

Comment: It exists so you can compose it with other functions?

Comment: @ThéophileChoutri yeah, that's also one of the more reasonably things it's used for, and which only works with the unsafe signature. (Unless you use Kleisli composition, but in that case you might as well stay in the list monad: `take 1` instead of `head`.) However, a composition with `head` is only safe you can guarantee that the first function yields a non-empty list, in which case there's a good chance its signature should actually be `-> NonEmpty A` rather than `-> [A]`.